# Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly. How to fix?

Tags: php, html, mysql, xampp

i was trying to run apache server , but gave this error messages as shown in screen shot , i tried diff stackoverflow solutions Like changing the port 80 to 81 and also deleted Skype which i never used , still getting this messages , I installed xampp in D:\xampp
I ran the app as [image: This is when i run xampp]administrator but of no use

Comment: please share the logs so we see what is happening

Comment: @Donkagunila , as there were no file named error.log and php_error_log so i created them but , when i restart the apache and try to see the logs they are empty , like the files are empty , 
I referred this for creating files : -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43247952/php-error-log-missing-in-xampp#:~:text=3%20Answers&text=Somehow%20PHP%20won't%20create,panel%20(stop%20and%20start).

Answer (score 1):

=> you can change your port 8080

=>=>change httpd.conf file open

=>click config right click and change poart add 8080 where 80

Listen 8080

ServerName localhost:8080

=>change httpd-ssl.conf file open

Listen 4433

ServerName [www.example.com:4433](http://www.example.com:4433)

Comment: ,I think there are lots of typos or steps are not clear , all i did is open xampp , click config tab (which is the first option at the very right side, above netstat option) -> service and port settings ->Changed Apache 2.4 Main port to 8080 , that's all i did

Comment: yoūr aache server̥ sṭar̥ṭ ña nōt.and you can run localhost:8080 your dashboard will be open.